# Why my RDS instance is not connecting with my Django project?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect my Django Project with a RDS instance with Postgre engine

It's a free tier option

The instance is running normally with no problems

I've set my Inbound Rule to allow Postgre connection with my IP

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'angtradingdatabase',
        'USER': 'vitor',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'angtradingdatabase.xxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

But I'm receiving this error when I try to run the 'python manage.py runserver' code

django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "angtradingdatabase.cbe1o6n4gvvs.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (18.117.34.123), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "angtradingdatabase" does not exist

The name of my database is angtradingdatabase as you can see in the picture, what is causing this problem??

Create new databases

Comment: Are you allowing remote connections to the database? That's a bad practice first at all. Have you tried to get access to the db from PgAdmin or a similar tool?

Comment: There is no picture. (Those are usually a poor way to share information anyway).

Comment: Either you didn't create a database in your instance or you got the database name wrong. See the troubleshooting section here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html#USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.Troubleshooting-DBname

Answer (score 0):

Different from your claim, the database indeed does not exist.

Note that database names are case sensitive.

Comment: Friend, my RDS Instance shows the 'DB identifier' filed as 'angtradingdatabase' and also the status is available, so correct me if I'm wrong but I think the db exists and is working

All the other db I've creates was exactly like this one

Comment: You don't have to guess. Connect and list the databases.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, for this connection to work you must set the 'Initial database name' as the name of your database and not just the 'DB identifier'

Anyway, tks for your help everyone!